# mongodb queries per second

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a server with 64G RAM and I am running a script which compares one million data in a csv file against the database. If matches are found, the script just prints the number of matches at the end of execution.

The script when ran, is taking 3 minutes to finish. Tested with 50,000, 1 lakh, 3 lakh, 5 lakh data files as well and the performance rate or the rate at which the script is executed is proportional. There is enough memory free in the server. The mongostat output when the script was running is pasted below. My questions is, I believe the script is executing close to 5000 queries per second. I have read in many posts, that they are getting an average of 50K queries per second. How can this be achieved? My server is running Ubuntu, 64 bit, and 24 cores.

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize res faults            locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time
    *0   3885     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    12g  24.2g 64m      0 db_list_restore:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0 380k   142k     2   03:09:26
    *0   4188     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    12g  24.2g 68m      0 db_list_restore:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0 410k   153k     2   03:09:27
    *0   4462     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    12g  24.2g 72m      0 db_list_restore:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0 440k   163k     2   03:09:28
    *0   4401     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    12g  24.2g 76m      0 db_list_restore:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0 435k   161k     2   03:09:29
    *0   4368     *0     *0       0     2|0       0    12g  24.2g 81m      0 db_list_restore:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0 432k   160k     2   03:09:30
    *0   4416     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    12g  24.2g 84m      0 db_list_restore:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0 437k   161k     2   03:09:31
    *0   4245     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    12g  24.2g 89m      0 db_list_restore:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0 420k   155k     2   03:09:32
    *0   4561     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    12g  24.2g 93m      0 db_list_restore:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0 451k   167k     2   03:09:33
    *0   3920     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    12g  24.2g 97m      0 db_list_restore:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0 388k   144k     2   03:09:34
    *0   4307     *0     *0       0     2|0       0    12g  24.2g 105m      0 db_list_restore:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0 426k   157k     2   03:09:35
```

Comment: It may be 50K queries per second but not per script, I would try using $in queries more, at the end of the day PHP cna only run so fast doing so many things at a time, plus the driver is sync not async

Comment: thanks Sammaye, is there anything on the server side that can be done to speed up performance?

Comment: I don't think so, that mongostat is pretty clean, I might be missing something but I think this is just the speed of PHP at the end of the day

Comment: Try to measure CPU and I/O load. As Sammaye suggests, your code is probably just waiting most of the time, as is MongoDB. Also, your code is probably single-threaded so there's 2-4 CPUs working on the code at best (with I/O handling on the third and some garbage collection on the fourth CPU). Try parallelizing the code if possible.

Answer (score 4):

These number look relatively reasonable for a single process doing all the work - depending on what sort of query you are doing of course.

In general you'll have thousands of webserver processes (depending on your application workload and cpu count, maybe only few hundreds), which will be generating the traffic - so you'll have thousands of sockets open to the server allowing you to scale whichever component in your infrastructure independently.

For a single process application you'll be stuck in "wait loops" as there is only so much individual resource is asked to do at each time so you will never be able to maximize your potential with only one process, one socket, one task. You want to occupy all your resources all the time.

To achieve this you would want to parallelize your workflow as much as you can. There is no predefined number of workers that is the correct answer, so how much work each process should be doing is something you'll have to figureout for yourself by trying it out.

If you have million entries in the CSV file, you may want to start dividing the work up in 10 pieaces, create 10 PHP processes that seek into the file and work read through 100.000 entries.
Benchmark that, and then maybe try 100 processes, each working on 10.000 entries at a time, and compare to the previous results.